# Constructor readonly parameter

Tags: typescript

I am analyzing some TypeScript code and I came across this kind of declaration inside a class definition:

```js
constructor(readonly constructorParam : Type) {
  // here we don't assign constructorParam to anything
}
```

But further, I see that `constructorParam` is used as normal.

Is it possible that it `constructorParam` property is "created and assigned be default"?

It also is wrapped in `export abstract class ... extends ... implements ...` (while `extends` and `implement` are understandable inheritance keywords, `export` is used for working with modules, but might be relevant to discussion).

**UPDATE**

According to [this post](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/read-only-properties-in-typescript), it really seems to work like that - creating property and assigning value by default for constructor parameters marked as `readonly`.

Comment: Yes that totally works and isn't only limited to `readonly`. It saves time assigning each parameter in the constructor. E.g. the following is also possible: `constructor(public randomVal: number) {}`

Comment: @r3dst0rm And it would create and assign property `randomVal` ?

Comment: Indeed. Assuming it were the constructor of `RandomClass`, using it like: `new RandomClass(5).randomVal` would return passed in number 5.

Comment: You can read about it here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#parameter-properties

Comment: Link to updated handbook: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#:~:text=Try-,Parameter%20Properties,-TypeScript%20offers%20special

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this article](https://kendaleiv.com/typescript-constructor-assignment-public-and-private-keywords/), there exists shorthand to declare all class properites as contructor parameters like:

```
constructor ( public someProp : number )
```

In this case `someProp` will be created. Obviously, this is fully qualified declaration, i.e. we have type declaration (`number` in this case) and access modifiers and more, so instead of `public` it could be, for example, `private readonly`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
constructor(readonly construcotrParam : Type = "Normal") {
  // here we don't assign construcotrParam to anything
}
```